# how to url mod rewrite in yii modules

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, yii-modules

I have following set of urls... using different modules in yii

```
www.abc.com/site1/home/user
www.abc.com/site2/home/user
www.abc.com/site3/home/user
```

I want to show like below

```
www.abc.com/home/user
www.abc.com/home/user
www.abc.com/home/user
```

Is this possible?

My htaccess file contains the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/site1/(.*)/$ /site1/home/user [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/site2/(.*)/$ /site2/home/user [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/site3/(.*)/$ /site3/home/user [L,NC]
```

Comment: you want to redirect www.abc.com/siteSOMENUMBER/home/user to www.abc.com/home/user ?or can you just get me the folder structure also

Comment: www.abc.com/site1/home/user 

is the actual link

i just want to remove the site1 folder from the url

Comment: are site1,site2 etc different folders? how do you recognize which folder(site1 or site2) you want to redirect if you simple get a url like this www.abc.com/home/use?

Comment: ya site1, site2, site3 are diffrent folders...

Comment: if you get the url like this www.abc.com/home/use, how do you understand which folder (site1, site2, site3) is to be executed

Comment: there look are different and also the functionality..